# Radio button set property of parent object with selected object

Tags: knockout.js

**Javascript:**

```
functional OrderViewModel() {
   this.selectedVehicle = ko.observable();

   this.vehicles = ko.observableArray([
    new VehicleViewModel('Toyota'),
    new VehicleViewModel('Ford'),
    new VehicleViewModel('Chevy')
   ]);
}


function VehicleViewModel(name) {
   this.name = name;
}


ko.applyBindings(new OrderViewModel());
```

**Html:**

```
<div>
    <!--ko foreach: $data.vehicles -->
        <label>
            <input type="radio" data-bind="value: $data.name, checked: $parent.selectedVehicle" />
            <span data-bind="text: $data.name"></span>
        </label>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

How do I make it update the "selectedVehicle" property of the OrderViewModel with the selected VehicleViewModel (instead of just the name)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically had it.  Look at this
https://jsfiddle.net/16hozLzL/

```
<div>
    <!--ko foreach: $data.vehicles -->
        <label>
            <input type="radio" data-bind="value: $data, checked: $parent.selectedVehicle" />
            <span data-bind="text: $data.name"></span>
        </label>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Just remove the .name from the values binding and it will bind the entire object

Comment: The thing is that sets the HTML value attribute to "[Object object]".....is that valid HTML (or 508 compliant)?

Comment: Dont know, but it is the solution you are looking for